# Как обновлять количество в item

Tags: android

Есть NavigationView у него имеется item (listview), у item есть количество (пример сообщения  количество 10), как мне обновлять количество или каждый раз перестраивать адаптер, мне кажется это не совсем правильно, подскажите как правильно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Покажите код, возможно станет понятнее суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Пример item в меню xml

Потом можно найти Layout через этот item и менять его содержимое где вам нужно